# Monitoring GWT JavaScript/Client-side code

Tags: javascript, performance, gwt, analysis, monitor

I would like to monitor each called client-side function with GWT.
I tried several GWT AOP frameworks. However, I did not find any that is compatible with GWT 2.7.

Has anybody managed to monitor each called client-side function? I'd like this to automatically monitor the performance of the client-side code. Manually adding events/calls is tedious in a 1k methods project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view/debug client-side JS code via GWT SuperDevMode.

Comment: And how can I programmatically get the call timestamp/duration and the called method name then?

Comment: I marked your hint as the answer since you led me to JavaScript AOP .Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.performance API:

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now

Answer (score 0):

Using https://code.google.com/p/jquery-aop/ it is "easy".

Create a native JSNI method such that you can access "this" as the local GWT module functions...:

```
public static native void weave() /*-{
    $wnd.jQuery.aop.around({
        target : this,
        method : 'viewScene.*'
    }, function(invocation) {
        var t0 = $wnd.performance.now();
        var result = invocation.proceed();
        var t1 = $wnd.performance.now();
        console.log("Call to " + invocation.method + " took " + (t1 - t0)
                + " milliseconds.")
        return result;
    });
}-*/;
```

The only challenge now is how to associate "function viewScene_0_g$" with the original code. However, this should be possible with the sourcemaps.

Comment: We have set up a small example how to monitor GWT 2.7 JS code: https://build.se.informatik.uni-kiel.de/gitlab/kieker/gwt-monitoringexamplewebapp